# Require parent component in directive AngularJS 1.5

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components

How to require a Component in a Directive? You can require the controller of a directive in another directive and you can require a component in another component. But how to require a components controller in a directive?

Directive:

```
export class Directive {

        require = "^^parentComponent";  
        restrict = "A";
        link = (scope, element, attrs, parentComponent) => {

    }

    app.directive("someDirective", /* Init code omitted for brewity */);
}
```

Html:

```
<parent-component>
     <div some-directive> </div>
</parent-component>
```

I Receive the following error:

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'parentComponent', required by directive 'someDirective', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$compile/ctreq?p0=InvoiceCre
```

Comment: `parentComponent` has controller?

Answer (score -1):

```
require: '^parentComponent'
```

works

http://plnkr.co/edit/Rm53sWSJfnl7IVFzTjm2?p=preview

Comment: It would also work for `^^test`, the difference between `^` & `^^` is require directive should be there in 1st parent & other could be anywhere inside a parent